# Can't seem to apply styles to Google MAP API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I trying to change the saturation for this instance of a Google map. Everything else is working EXCEPT the saturation style. What am i doing wrong ?

Code:

```
$(function() { // when the document is ready to be manipulated.
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { // if the browser is compatible with Google Map's
        var map = document.getElementById("myMap"); // Get div element
        var m = new GMap2(map); // new instance of the GMap2 class and pass in our div location.

        m.setCenter(new GLatLng(59.334951,18.088598), 13); // pass in latitude, longitude, and zoom level.
        m.openInfoWindow(m.getCenter(), document.createTextNode("Looking Good")); // displays the text
        m.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP); // sets the default mode. G_NORMAL_MAP, G_HYBRID_MAP

        // var c = new GMapTypeControl(); // switch map modes
        // m.addControl(c);

        // m.addControl(new GLargeMapControl()); // creates the zoom feature

        var styleArray = [
            {
                featureType: "all",
                stylers: [
                    {saturation: -80}
                ]
            }
        ];
    }
    else {
        alert("Upgrade your browser, man!");
    }
});
```

I have been searching all day (and failing) to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a line like:

```
m.setOptions({styles: styleArray});
```

Somewhere after you've declared the styler? The above line will apply the styles you created to the map that you have.

Comment: Hi Shauna, nope, but i tried adding it bellow the style, with no change in the results
 like this:

var styleArray = [
{
featureType: "all",
stylers: [
{ saturation: -80 }
]
}
];
m.setOptions({styles: styleArray});

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools console and see if there are any JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `styleArray` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help i finally figured it out. Feeling a bit stupid but the "m.setOtions" is apparently a function of V3 API and i was using V2.